# Partially erase type parameter in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I’m not entirely sure of the right terminology to explain my question, so here’s a very simplified example to hopefully explain what I'm looking for.

Let’s say I have a generic class like this:

```js
class MyStorage<T> {
  // … (omitted members that make class invariant)
  get(key: string): T {…}
  set(key: string, value: T): {…}
}
```

I’ve intentionally made this class invariant so it can’t be silently coerced to a broader `T`:

```js
const stringStorage = new MyStorage<string>(…);
// Compiler error due to type mismatch. If this were allowed, unknownStorage
// could be used to put *anything* into stringStorage.
const unknownStorage: MyStorage<unknown> = stringStorage;
```

This works great, and catches errors caused by accidental broadening of `T`. However, sometimes it would be useful to be able to hold a reference to an instance of MyStorage with a constraint on `T` without having to know it's exact type. E.g.,

```js
// Made up syntax. storage is a MyStorage of some erased type that extends U.
function readsFromStorage<U>(arg: U, storage: MyStorage<? extends U>) {
  // Valid. We know get() returns a type that extends U.
  const value: U = storage.get('mykey');
  // Compiler error. The erased T might be a narrow type than U.
  storage.set('mykey', arg);
}
```

or alternatively:

```js
// Made up syntax. storage is a MyStorage of some erased type extended by U.
function writesToStorage<U>(arg: U, storage: MyStorage<U extends ?>) {
  // Valid. We know that set() takes a type extended by U.
  storage.set('mykey', arg);
  // Compiler error. U might be narrower than the erased T type.
  const value: U = storage.get('mykey');
}
```

Usually, this would be useful when another generic class wants to store a reference to a `MyStorage<T>`, but doesn’t care about the exact type of `T`.

Is this possible to express in today’s TypeScript? If not, is there an existing feature request that would cover it?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates what you're talking about.  [That class definition isn't invariant in `T`](https://tsplay.dev/WzoRRw) because class methods are checked bivariantly in TypeScript.

Comment: You could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/mx5RZW) with two type parameters; if that doesn't meet your needs, you should make your [mre] include the failing use case for that.  Typescript doesn't have "erasable"/"wildcard" or any other existentially quantified type parameters, so the easiest way to handle this would be with an extra type parameter that you don't really care about... but without more explicit use cases it's hard to see if that works for you.